# ForEach in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift5

When use ScrollView and ForEach looks like the following code  :

```
ScrollView(.horizontal,showsIndicators: false) {
                HStack {
                    ForEach(self.QUOTES, id: \.self) { qt in
                        Text(qt)
                    }
                }
            }
```

Its ok and no problem. 
But when I want to use any code (like adding a image) in ForEach block like the following code  :

```
ScrollView(.horizontal,showsIndicators: false) {
                HStack {
                    ForEach(self.QUOTES, id: \.self) { qt in
                        Text(qt)
                        Image(systemName: "a.square.fill")
                               .resizable()
                               .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
                    }
                }
            }
```

I get the following error while writing : 
Unable to infer complex closure return type; add explicit type to disambiguate

Comment: Have you tried putting your `Text` and `Image` in some kind of stack? Stack or Hstack? Honestly, and meant with **no** offense, this is pretty basic SwiftUI. Maybe your HStack is too... outer... in the FroEach. But stat with something more simple≥ Maybe A `List`. Or maybe a `View`. Move that into it's *own* struct. (My choice? a `Button`. Who cares if it doesn't do anything. Get it laid out like you wish.) As is, you need to either `Group` your code or use a stack of some source. But also? As is, your question doesn't help to say which.

Answer (score 4):

The `ForEach` struct needs to contain a single view so you'll need to group the text and image or embed them in a stack depending on how you want the layout to render.

```
ScrollView(.horizontal,showsIndicators: false) {
    HStack {
        ForEach(self.QUOTES, id: \.self) { qt in
            Group {
                Text(qt)
                Image(systemName: "a.square.fill")
                       .resizable()
                       .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
            }
        }
    }
}
```